# Custom ActionBar and overflow menu

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I am implementing custom ActionBar, how should I handle the overflow menu (3 dots icon on the right here: http://developer.android.com/images/ui/actionbar.png)? The overflow menu should be visible if there is no hardware menu button - but how can I detect that?

I'm not using the system ActionBar, because I need a customized behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ViewConfiguration.get(context).hasPermanentMenuKey()
```

Answer (score 0):

The menu button is [somewhat outdated](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2012/01/say-goodbye-to-menu-button.html), maybe you want to reconsider and stick to the overflow menu? And by the way, do you know http://actionbarsherlock.com/ ?

Comment: Android 4.0 ActionBar hides the overflow menu on devices which have HW menu button. I want to emulate this behavior. I can't use system ActionBar or ActionBarSherlock, because I need a very specific behavior which is not possible to achieve with ABS.

Comment: OK, just thought you could fork ABS and implement your specific behavior on top of it. Did you check Androids source yet?

Comment: I have looked into the source and found the code that checks for HW menu button presence, I will post an answer in a minute :)

Answer (score 0):

```
try {
    ViewConfiguration config = ViewConfiguration.get(this);
    Field menuKeyField = ViewConfiguration.class.getDeclaredField("sHasPermanentMenuKey");


        if (menuKeyField != null) {
            menuKeyField.setAccessible(true);
            menuKeyField.setBoolean(config, false);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();

}
```

}